# Creating a custom Woocommerce product modal on click

Tags: php, wordpress, html, woocommerce

I have created a basic HTML/jQuery structure for a modal that will pop up when clicked on. I'm in the process of integrating Woocommerce into my site and am unsure as to how I can do the following:

- Have modal load respective product info
- Integrate into a Woocommerce loop

Here is my HTML for the skeleton of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
         <div class="col-md-4"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/media/temp_product_images/Alto-183x300.jpg" alt="Product Img" class="product-img" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                    <p class="product-img-title text-center">Alto</p>
                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="myModalLabel">Alto</h4> </div>
                                <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body-one">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-4"> <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/media/temp_product_images/Alto-183x300.jpg" alt="Modal Product Img" id="product-img"> </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-7">
                                            <h5>Colours</h5>
                                            <div class="scroll-container">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                                                        <div class="selected-product-color"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/media/temp_product_images/MACASSA.jpg" alt="Product Colour">
                                                            <p>Macassa</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>
                                                <!-- End of Test Case -->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-1">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn flip"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Prices -->
                                <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body-two">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-11">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <h5 id="modal-prices">Download Price List</h5></div>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <?php $my_query = new WP_Query('p=47');
                                                    while($my_query->have_posts()){
                                                        $my_query->the_post();
                                                        the_content();
                                                            } ?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-1">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn flip"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer"> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'Contact' ) ) ?>" class="btn btn-default">Get Quote</a> </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End of Modal -->
                </div>
```

And here is my jQuery:

```
//Modal Change Content
$('#modal-body-two').hide();
$('.flip').on('click', function () {
    $('#modal-body-one, #modal-body-two').toggle()
});
```

Is there a way that I can display the product info on click within a modal using Woocommerce? Thanks